# Problems with TOC section depth

Tags: table-of-contents

I have set my TOC depth to 4, but unfortunatelly when I do that, the sections which have less depth add one more line and so it repeats the number withouth any need. Can you please help with that? Check the image.

[image]

My code

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
 {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\makeatother
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
%%Starting TOC
\tableofcontents

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Sumário}
```

Comment: We can't process your example code. What is the class? What is the body of the document? Please provide a complete example code showing the problem from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`.